# What is the best way to integrate Picasa and JSF-software?

Tags: jsf, integration, picasa

I am implementing small software with JSF. I would like to show users' photos from Picasa, but I have no idea what is the best way to do it? There can be many users and everyone of them has their own Picasa albums.

What do you recommend and why? Is it the wisest to use already implemented JavaScript-softwares like JQuery plugins or Googles Picasa Web Albums Data API to fetch photos etc?

Thanks!
Sami

EDIT:

Have you or somebody else tried Fancybox, I have problems with js and css-files and I think that because of paths to those files. What is the correct way to refer to JS and CSS-files in JSF-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a jQuery based solution like [Picasa Webalbum Integrator](http://code.google.com/p/pwi/). All you have to do is to add the required script files to your page and call the needed function, passing it the username of the gallery, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  //-- default jQuery call, do stuff when page is loaded
    $("#container").pwi({  //--specify your DIV's ID here
        username: '#{user.userName}' 
    });
});
</script>
```

Where #{user.userName} is an EL expression pointing to the name of the user which gallery you want to show.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I will try that and let you know how I survived. I think that Googles API is little bit too much because I am just showing pictures, nothing else?

Comment: This is cool :) I just added  <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.pwi.js" /> this one because I am using facelets and I had a problem to find js-files. What you think about fancybox, seems nice?

Comment: One more. Have you an idea how to get this working with Primefaces and JSF? I am using Primefaces layouts and templates and I can't get it working. $(document).ready(function () {
        var settings = {
          username: 'testing'
          
          };
        $("#container").pwi(settings);
      }); This just disappears when I insert it to the template and the template is blank page after that.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake!

Two things what you have to remember when using jquery plugins with JSF.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="pwi.css"  />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.pwi.js" />
```

You have to use those tags. I used only h:outputScript for both of them and it seems to be ok, but of course not, generated html wasn't ok.

Other thing was that:

```
 <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

I am using jquery with is in Primefaces, without it there is a conflict between jquery versions or pwi doesn't find jquery at all. At least I think so :) No everything is working fine, so I am happy!

Sami